# volley- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I am trying to implement Volley library in my app which uses json. But everytime I run it the app freezes and crashes showing this log message. I cant figure out what the problem is?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36089274 byte allocation with 16769200 free bytes and 16MB until OOM
                                                                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                                                                  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                                                                  at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                                                                  at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                                                                  at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
                                                                  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                                                                  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                                                                  at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:60)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:44)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
                                                                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is used too much memory.
Use NDK or if you need more a bit use in AndroidManifest.xml in application tag
`android:largeHeap=true`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Image/Bitmap you're trying to show is too big. Usually happens when image is 1mb+
Display bitmaps more efficiently
To fix this you can check this out
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

How big is this response you're processing with Volley? You've run out of memory because Volley is trying to write a 36mb string into your memory.

Either hit a different end point returning less data or look into using a different library that supports streaming your response.

(Volley is not suited to streaming large amounts of data [link](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html))

Comment: It is not that much. Here's the json url: https://yts.ag/api/v2/movie_details.json?movie_id=10

Comment: We might need to see more code, according to that stack trace you're allocating a string buffer of 36089274 bytes